# Page does not update after deep link to same page is clicked

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I am using React-navigation to handle deep link.

Let's say I am in BusinessProfile Page that is currently displaying detail for ***BUSINESS B1***. I click on home button and minimize my app. When I click on a deep link, **myapp://BusinessProfilePage/B2**, It takes me to the BusinessProfile Page but still displays result for Business B1. The function to get business detail for B2 is not called.

How can I make the page refresh when a page opens from a deep link.

P.S. I cannot call the function in componentDidUpdate because when the function to get Business Detail is called, it updates the state which then evoke componentDidMount again.

Answer (score 0):

You should call your function in a listener for the `change` event of `AppState`:

```
import { AppState } from 'react-native';

componentDidMount() {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
}

_handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
  if (nextAppState === 'active') { // App has come to the foreground
    if(this.state.currentBusiness.ID != (ID received in deep link)) // Need to get data
         this.getBusiness(ID received in deep link);
  }
 };
```

Taking my best guess here with regards to variable names as you didn't provide any code (you should always include code samples when describing your issue :) ), but you get the idea.

Comment: i'm using react navigation's focus to reload my screen but it is not helping as well @iuliu.net

Answer (score 0):

For v5 Use following prop which is alternate to 'key' option in navigate.

```
      getId={({ params }) => params.id}
```

In this case id will be different. In your case it will be 'B1' and 'B2'. This will create multiple instance of same screen.